# How can I connect a VPN and VLAN via a Cisco ASA?

Tags: vpn, cisco, vlan

I'm trying to extend a VPN further into an organisation:

At the main location I have a private network (call it 192.168.0.0/24) which is connected via a Cisco ASA 5510 to a Draytek ADSL router. The remote location also has a private network (call it 192.168.1.0/24) connected directly to their Draytek ADSL router.

The Cisco ASA and remote Draytek have a site-to-site IPSec VPN configured so that we can talk securely to their internal network devices. This setup is replicated a few times (192.168.2.0/24, etc.).

Is there a way to bring the remote private networks onto ours via VLANs on the ASA, so that I could have a VLAN-capable switch with port 1 on 192.168.1.0, port 2 on 192.168.2.0, etc. for testing and configuration purposes?

Comment: What kind of access you need to allow? I mean what is the final goal of this connection. You have so many options depending on your  budget, manageability and performance.

Comment: The aim is to be able to bring up new servers at the central location and work on them while they're being configured for use at the intended remote site, and to be able to demonstrate these machines before they physically have to be removed.

Comment: There's no budget for further hardware, though all our switches are VLAN-capable. Performance isn't a major issue, as this is not a production scenario, and I'm thinking that these connections will be live all the time so they just have to come back OK if the connection is interrupted.

Comment: Ipsec will not encapsulate Layer2 traffic, if that's what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cisco (IOS running) routers or Juniper's SRX line (among many others) can do this bridging a layer 2 segment over GRE, L2TP (or for more complex cases MPLS as CCC or VPLS).

For cheaper options Mikrotik's hardware should also be able to do this.

If you have a spare Linux machine at each end OpenVPN has a bridge mode which should work.

This can get fairly complex quite quickly (for example handling the MTU correctly takes quite a bit of care).

Comment: Essentially, I want the ASA to connect VPN 1 to VLAN 10, VPN 2 to VLAN 20, etc., then trunk those VLANs to another switch in our network, so that if I plug something into port 2 of the switch, I'm in the same broadcast domain as the devices on the remote network.

Answer (score 1):

The ASAs act as routers, aka Layer3 / Ip  device.
Through them you have a route from  your local networks ( 192.168.0.0/24 ) to remote networks ( 192.168.1.0/24 ) .

Vlan is Layer2, there is no IP address.

If you want to propagate a vlan across routers you need to encapsulate layer2 traffic into ip traffic. [vtun](http://vtun.sourceforge.net/) might do the trick but it will certainly be very disappointing in terms of performance, and the setup will be ugly ( you need to install it on two linux/bsd servers at each point, and bridge the vtap interfaces to your lans .. ). Anyway the ASAs will have no role in this.

Comment: Essentially, I want the ASA to connect VPN 1 to VLAN 10, VPN 2 to VLAN 20, etc., then trunk those VLANs to another switch in our network, so that if I plug something into port 2 of the switch, I'm in the same broadcast domain as the devices on the remote network.

Comment: You will not do this with ASA, look at @LapTop006 for suggested solutions.